# Kendochart (latest version2013) is not supported ubuntu os?

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui

While i am testing my application in Ubuntu operating system after loading data graph is like unselected,it's not allow to do any other task in application.Why it's not supporting i am using latest version 2013 chart

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: google chrome version 28 and firefox.in firefox data is also not loading

Comment: can any one help why it's not supporting?

Comment: If data is having more 1000 it's happening

Comment: And some controls are not working or not  supporting in firebox Ubuntu os.

Comment: Did you check the browser's javascript console for any errors? Can you create a jsfiddle?